# Yup validation with Date object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, yup

Our current project structure includes a form validation using Yup with TypeScript. We started using it like this:

```
// Used as a type in `useForm` from `react-hook-form`
export type MySlideSchemaType = {
  questionField: string
}

// Used with `useForm` as a `resolver`
export const mySlideSchema: yup.SchemaOf<MySlideSchemaType> =
  yup.object({
    questionField: yup.string().required()
  })
```

The TypeScript validation in the example above is correct - it do not cause any errors and even suggest fields that should be used in `mySlideSchema` to match `MySlideSchemaType` as expected.

---

The problem occures when we are using a `Date` object. Yup does have a custom method called `date` which I assumed would match the `Date` object type from javaScript. But I was wrong and we are getting an error.

```
// Used as a type in `useForm` from `react-hook-form`
export type MySlideSchemaType = {
  questionField: Date
}

// Used with `useForm` as a `resolver`
export const mySlideSchema: yup.SchemaOf<MySlideSchemaType> =
  yup.object({
    questionField: yup.date().required()
  })
```

Intellij error:

```
The types of 'fields.questionField' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'RequiredDateSchema<Date, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'ObjectSchemaOf<Date> | ObjectSchemaOf<Lazy<Date, never>>'.
    Type 'RequiredDateSchema<Date, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'ObjectSchemaOf<Lazy<Date, never>>'.
```

---

How can I implement a date object type in yup schema?

Comment: Looks good in v 0.32.11: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-validationschema-forked-o880t?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: You are right! Fixed in 0.32.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed validation problem in yup version 0.32.11